# Why is average velocity taken as total displacement/total time?

Tags: kinematics

Average of anything is that value  which lies exactly midway between its two extreme values(highest and lowest). So, average velocity should be the median value of all the values of velocity that the object has during motion. What the ratio of total displacement  to the total time gives us is the velocity of the object had the body traversed the distance in a straight line with constant magnitude. Why do we call this value as the average velocity ?

Comment: Median is the "average" you refer to in the first sentence. *Mean* is a different type of average and is only the same as the median for a limited number of symmetric distributions of data.

Comment: Let's say Alice took a walk from her apartment to her lecture hall. Her (smart) watch tells her that she has walked a total of 500 meters. It takes her 5 minutes to cover this distance. Depending on what we want to investigate, Alice's average speed 500/5 = 100 meters/minute might be a useful metric to know. Or it might not. If we are investigating how easily distracted Alice is, variances from this walking speed, or how many times she stopped on the way to class might be a better metric to analyze. Ultimately, the raw data matters, and any analytics on top of it is up to the investigator.

Comment: What is the average of: 1,2,3,4,10? It is 4, which doesn't lie exactly midway between extremes. You are thinking of the median.

Comment: You are defining average and median as identical. That is not true. Average is defined differently. Specifically, the median does not take into account any weight of any values - it just takes the middle value while ignoring the others. (Arithmetic) average on the other hand does take into account the weight of the averaged values so that larger values 'weigh more' so the average is skewed towards them.

Comment: Note that velocity vs. time is a continuous function, meaning that it has an infinite number of values.  Thus, average velocity is not determined by averaging the highest and lowest values.  For more info, see the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Well, using a standard way to calculate averages:

$$v=\frac{dr}{dt} \to \bar{v}=\frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{t_0}^{t_f}v \ dt=\frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{t_0}^{t_f}\frac{dr}{dt}dt=\frac{\Delta r}{\Delta t}$$

Where $\Delta r$ is the displacement.

Answer (score 0):

Well your understanding of average is a bit flawed. Average is never explicitly equal to median. For example if I have discrete set of numbers, the chances are that Averag is not equal to median.

Calculus way, we define average velocity as:

$$<v>_{0\rightarrow t}=\frac{\int_0^t v(t)dt}{\int_0^t dt}$$

Generally for any function:
$$f(x)_{0\rightarrow x}=\frac{\int_0^x f(x)dx}{\int_0^x dx}$$